# How to create a priority scheduler for io_context?

Tags: c++, c++20, boost-asio, c++-coroutine

I'm writing an ASIO application that is latency-sensitive after some events. I would like each of the coroutines to have a priority associated with it. Latency-sensitive coroutines would always be executed before the others. (There will actually be more priority levels than two but the basic idea is that a higher level always takes precedence before lower ones. Starving lower levels is acceptable.)

Coroutines might communicate between different priority levels. For example, they might `co_spawn` a coroutine at a level different from their own or they might raise/lower a semaphore that a coroutine at a different level is waiting on.

How can I do that? There is the old example of a priority scheduler at https://live.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp14/executors/priority_scheduler.cpp but that works with a context that is not an `io_context`. I suspect that I cannot run coroutines performing IO operations with this.

My application is single-threaded, in case that matters. At least for now.

My current idea is to:

1. Instead of a single `io_context` object have multiple: one for each of the priority levels.
2. Instead of running a single `io_context::run()` have my own event loop that runs `io_contexts[high_priority].poll_one()` and only if that returns 0 run `io_contexts[lower_priority].poll_one()`

The documentation is scarce but I'm getting a strong sense that this is not the way that ASIO designers intended. I'm worried I might run into trouble regarding performance or communication between coroutines running on different io_contexts.

I'm getting a strong sense that there should be a single io_context with multiple executors, analogously to the example linked above.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

First off, the sketch you provide with separate io_contexts looks smart - in the sense that it should work. I suspect you are right that doing it that way will "opt out" of a lot of optimization room that's internal to `io_context` and its executors.

I'd like to note that I don't think the `priority_scheduler` example is old - on the contrary. But I will admit it doesn't integrate with any of Asio's execution contexts (which have their own scheduler) and it's non-trivial to see whether it can be integrated. I'm not currently sure myself. I suspect the example is in the "c++14 executor" section because it was intended as part of a (standards) proposal for the networking workgroup¹, and a such is very detail-oriented. In that sense it is a powerful example demonstrating how orthogonal Asio models and concepts can be applied independently.

---

What I **can** offer is another example that may be of inspiration: [Invocation: prioritised handlers](https://live.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp03/invocation/prioritised_handlers.cpp), which is under the c++03 examples.

It, too, inverts some of the control from the scheduler, in that uses a custom executor to cause handlers to be pushed to a priority queue and then execute handlers from that queue:

```
boost::asio::io_context io_context;

handler_priority_queue pri_queue;

// Post a completion handler to be run immediately.
boost::asio::post(io_context, pri_queue.wrap(0, low_priority_handler));

// Start an asynchronous accept that will complete immediately.
tcp::endpoint endpoint(boost::asio::ip::address_v4::loopback(), 0);
tcp::acceptor acceptor(io_context, endpoint);
tcp::socket   server_socket(io_context);
acceptor.async_accept(server_socket, pri_queue.wrap(100, high_priority_handler));
tcp::socket client_socket(io_context);
client_socket.connect(acceptor.local_endpoint());

// Set a deadline timer to expire immediately.
boost::asio::steady_timer timer(io_context);
timer.expires_at(boost::asio::steady_timer::time_point::min());
timer.async_wait(pri_queue.wrap(42, middle_priority_handler));

while (io_context.run_one()) {
    // The custom invocation hook adds the handlers to the priority queue
    // rather than executing them from within the poll_one() call.
    while (io_context.poll_one())
        ;

    pri_queue.execute_all();
}
```

I feel that a few optimizations can be copied from the c++14 example (in particular the type-erasure instead of `std::function`² and some instances of move-aware handler support).

(¹ loosely naming because I have stayed away from politics and organizational structure in the ISO committee and workgroups - it's not something I try to follow)

(² Note that the pattern used in the c++14 example is pretty important around the order in which resources are freed before invocation of the handler. This subtle point is important to retain the allocation ordering guarantees of Asio: *["As noted previously, all resources must be released prior to calling the completion handler. This enables memory to be recycled for subsequent asynchronous operations within an agent. This allows applications with long-lived asynchronous agents to have no hot-path memory allocations, even though the user code is unaware of associated allocators"](https://live.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/model/allocators.html)*